# Using complete option for jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gif image in my html. I want to make the image "walk" so I'm using jquery `.animate()` the walking is fine, now, once it reaches the other side of the screen, I'd like to hide the image so I'm trying to use the complete option. My code looks like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
for(var i = 0; i < 500; i = i + 20) {
         $("#animate-gif").animate({backgroundPositionX: i}, 50, 
             function() { alert("finished"); }); }
});
```

However, the alert does not show. I've also tried doing the following:

```
duration : 50, complete : function()

{backgroundPositionX: i}, {duration : 50, complete :function()
```

But neither worked and I'm getting a warning in my debugger "Unexpected token :". So my question is, how exactly do you add a complete option for the animate function in jquery? I've tried looking through the documentation and some examples and what i've tried are pretty much what I've seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the purpose of the for loop. Try just calling animate() once:

http://jsfiddle.net/W5SjR/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#animate-gif").animate({backgroundPositionX: "100%"}, 500, function() { alert("finished"); });
});
```

Your complete function looks fine. Is it possible that you checked "don't allow this page to show popups"?

I would also suggest using console.log() instead of alert().

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure either why I used a for loop. Seems like my common sense took a break when I created this earlier. Anyway, you're right about checking the "don't allow this page to show popups". I reopened the page using a new tab and the alert box started showing. Thanks.

Comment: $.animate() is non-blocking anyway. That for loop will finish almost instantly, spawning 25 animate calls. If you need to chain animations, you have to spawn the 2nd one from the complete handler, or use a different pattern such as a promise.

Answer (score 0):

the general syntax of `.animate` is

```
$("selector").animate({"param":"value","param","value"},time,callback_function);
```

The callback function will be called after the completion of the animation

there are also other options like `"step", "complete"` and much more

You can check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz8rC/15/) where i would used some of them